# $error=array() doesn't store errors and not displaying it.

Tags: php, storage

Hey can annyone view my code and explain? $error = array() doesnt store my errors and 
$error[] = 'Wrong username or password!'; dont working. I need display my error at same page as i have login script.

```
  <?php


$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="2"; // Database name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    $error = array();//Declare An Array to store any error message 
};  
// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
//store data:
$_SESSION['$myusername'];
$_SESSION['$mypassword']; 
//next page:

header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
 $error[] = 'Wrong username or password!';
};
?>

ty!
```

Comment: So you have added the error message to an array, and it is syntactically correct. Show the code where you actually try to _display_ the error messages.

Comment: Lose the `;` at `};` in your last line, by the way.

Comment: I try to display it in form so what i have to do? (don't be angry im newbie in php and design :D)

Comment: Please post the code as I asked. it's as simple as looping over the array and displaying each message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<?php
if(isset($error) && is_array($error))
{
   echo "<div class='error'>" . implode("<br />", $error) . "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much i got solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ty Michael! I got it! :D
It should look like this:

```
  <?php  echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
            foreach ($error as $key => $values) {

                echo '  <li>'.$values.'</li>';



            }

?>
```